# Looping in a multidimensionnal array dynamically and flatten object inside it

Tags: javascript

everybody.
I will need to browse an array dynamically and flatten the objects it contains, knowing that it may evolve and contain an extra dimension.

for example the table contains this

```
const myArray = [
         {
           key: "CED", 
           label: "CEDRIC", 
           sub : null
         },
         {
           key: "AR", 
           label: "ARNAUD", 
           sub : [
                  {
                   key: "LUC", 
                   label: "LUCAS", 
                   sub : null
                  }
                 ]
         },
         {
           key: "PET", 
           label: "PETER", 
           sub : [
                  {
                   key: "JO", 
                   label: "JOHN", 
                   sub : null
                  },
                  {
                   key: "LUD", 
                   label: "LUDO", 
                   sub : [
                          {
                           key: "THO", 
                           label: "THOMAS", 
                           sub : null
                          }
                         ]
                  }
                 ]
         },
         {
           key: "TER", 
           label: "TERRY", 
           sub : null
         }
      ]
```

the expected output is

```
[
 {key: "CED", label: "CEDRIC"},
 {key: "AR", label: "ARNAUD"}, 
 {key: "LUC", label: "LUCAS"},
 {key: "PET", label: "PETER"},
 {key: "JO", label: "JOHN"},
 {key: "LUD", label: "LUDO"},
 {key: "THO", label: "THOMAS"},
 {key: "TER", label: "TERRY"}
]
```

I tried with a map, forEach, reduce etc but i also have to manually go down in the tree.

```
  const test = myArray.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    return []
      .concat(
        accumulator,
        value,
        value.sub && value.sub?.reduce((acc, val) => [].concat(acc, val))
      ).filter((val) => val !== null);
  }); // Output only the first and 2 level
```

would anyone have a way to do it dynamically without me having to worry about how many sub-dimensions there are?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
const out = myArray.reduce(function next(r, {key, label, sub}) {
    return [...r, {key, label}, ...(null === sub ? [] : sub.reduce(next, []))];
}, []);
```

Note the named inline function. It will not *pollute* the global namespace, yet will still be usable inside the function, allowing for an easy way to *recurse* deeper.

```js
const myArray = [
    {
        key: "CED",
        label: "CEDRIC",
        sub : null
    },
    {
        key: "AR",
        label: "ARNAUD",
        sub : [
            {
                key: "LUC",
                label: "LUCAS",
                sub : null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "PET",
        label: "PETER",
        sub : [
            {
                key: "JO",
                label: "JOHN",
                sub : null
            },
            {
                key: "LUD",
                label: "LUDO",
                sub : [
                    {
                        key: "THO",
                        label: "THOMAS",
                        sub : null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "TER",
        label: "TERRY",
        sub : null
    }
];

const out = myArray.reduce(function next(r, {key, label, sub}) {
    return [...r, {key, label}, ...(null === sub ? [] : sub.reduce(next, []))];
}, []);


console.log(out);
```

Comment: I like this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion to achieve this like shown:

```js
const myArray = [{
            key: "CED",
            label: "CEDRIC",
            sub: null
        },
        {
            key: "AR",
            label: "ARNAUD",
            sub: [{
                key: "LUC",
                label: "LUCAS",
                sub: null
            }]
        },
        {
            key: "PET",
            label: "PETER",
            sub: [{
                    key: "JO",
                    label: "JOHN",
                    sub: null
                },
                {
                    key: "LUD",
                    label: "LUDO",
                    sub: [{
                        key: "THO",
                        label: "THOMAS",
                        sub: null
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            key: "TER",
            label: "TERRY",
            sub: null
        }
    ]

    results = []

    function getPair(myArray) {
        myArray.map(item => {
            results.push({
                key: item.key,
                label: item.label
            })
            if (item.sub != null) {
                getPair(item.sub);
            }
        })
    }

    getPair(myArray);

    console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with foreach through your array and if there is a sub-array go recursivly ahead.

```js
function flatMyArray(array) {
    let result = [];
    array.forEach(obj => {
        result.push({key: obj.key, label: obj.label});
        if (obj.sub) {
            result = result.concat(flatMyArray(obj.sub));
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const myArray = [
         {
           key: "CED", 
           label: "CEDRIC", 
           sub : null
         },
         {
           key: "AR", 
           label: "ARNAUD", 
           sub : [
                  {
                   key: "LUC", 
                   label: "LUCAS", 
                   sub : null
                  }
                 ]
         },
         {
           key: "PET", 
           label: "PETER", 
           sub : [
                  {
                   key: "JO", 
                   label: "JOHN", 
                   sub : null
                  },
                  {
                   key: "LUD", 
                   label: "LUDO", 
                   sub : [
                          {
                           key: "THO", 
                           label: "THOMAS", 
                           sub : null
                          }
                         ]
                  }
                 ]
         },
         {
           key: "TER", 
           label: "TERRY", 
           sub : null
         }
      ];
      
  console.log(flatMyArray(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```js
function traverse(item) {
    if (item.key) 
        output.push({ key: item.key, label: item.label });  
    if (!item.sub)
        return;
    for (var x of item.sub) {
        traverse(x);
    }
}

const myArray = [
    {
        key: "CED",
        label: "CEDRIC",
        sub: null
    },
    {
        key: "AR",
        label: "ARNAUD",
        sub: [
            {
                key: "LUC",
                label: "LUCAS",
                sub: null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "PET",
        label: "PETER",
        sub: [
            {
                key: "JO",
                label: "JOHN",
                sub: null
            },
            {
                key: "LUD",
                label: "LUDO",
                sub: [
                    {
                        key: "THO",
                        label: "THOMAS",
                        sub: null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "TER",
        label: "TERRY",
        sub: null
    }
];

var output = [];
traverse({ sub: myArray });
console.log(output);
```